# Wordpress Page Template: Comment Filtering with Querystring

Tags: comments, page-template, query-string

A custom [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) was developed in order to display a list of products.

A WordPress page (/products) was created and the template was applied to it.  There is a database which the template's programming accesses to retrieve product information.  Different products are displayed based on a GET querystring variable, "Id" (/products?Id=1).

Comments are enabled on the /products page, so when users are viewing different products, they can comment.  The issue here is that the comments are common to the products page.  When a user comments on the product with Id = 1, the comment is displayed on all other product pages (Id = 2, 3, etc).  Optimally, we would want each product to have it's own set of comments.

What's the easiest way to implement the desired functionality on the products page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that short of creating your own comment tracking system.

Probably the easiest way to use Wordpress's functionality would be to make a "projects" [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) and use [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to store product information like the id etc. This would allow commenting on each product and you could use get_posts to display all posts of type product on your projects page.